# Alternative to a Minipage page breaks

Tags: lists, minipage

I would like to have a replacement for my minipage design of this exercise environment. I recently learned that minipages are unbreakable across page boundaries. And as a novice to the TeX/LaTeX programming system, I am finding it a bit difficult to grasp the its internals. So I would appreciate any help I can get - I have looked at a couple of packages, such as, adjustwidth and tcolorbox, but with little success.
The end result I'm hoping to get is an algorithm that would let help my exercise environment break across page boundaries.
Let me also say that I am quite to new to the group and the site so I don't know how the point scoring system works.
 Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem,environ,calc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,bm}
%\usepackage{showframe}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Redefining Section Command
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection
                    {section}%                                 %% name
                    {1}%                                       %% level
                    {0pt}%                                     %% no indent from left margin
                    {-1\baselineskip minus\parskip}%           %% beforeskip
                    {0.4\baselineskip}%                        %% afterskip
                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\raggedright}}% %% style
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Redefining Subsection Command
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection
                        {subsection}%
                        {2}%
                        {0pt}%
                        {-\baselineskip}%
                        {0.2\baselineskip}%
                        {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\raggedright}}%
\makeatother
%%==============================================================================
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}[section]
\numberwithin{exer}{chapter}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% following command definitions are used in the new exercise environments
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\exername}{}
\newcommand{\sbast}{\ensuremath{^{\bm{\ast}}\mkern-1.1mu}}
\newcommand{\nbast}{\ensuremath{\phantom{\sbast}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% new theoremstyle for Exercises: asterisked/starred exercise) theoremstyle
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheoremstyle{starredexercises}                        %% Name
{5pt plus1pt minus1pt}                                    %% Space above (or before) the environment
{5pt plus1pt minus1pt}                                    %% Space below (or after) the environment
{\normalfont}                                             %% Style Body font
%{\normalfont\small}                                       %% Style Body font
{0pt}                                                     %% Indentation of 1st Line of body text
{\normalfont}                                             %% Style Head font
{}                                                        %% Head Punctuation after head Style
{0pt}                                                     %% Horizontal space after Head Style
{\sbast\thmnumber{#2.}~\thmname{#1}\thmnote{~{\normalfont(#3)}}}%% Custom Theorem Head SPEC
%%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\theoremstyle{starredexercises}
\newtheorem{sqfexercises}[exer]{\protect\exername}
%%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\environfinalcode{\ignorespacesafterend}
\NewEnviron{sexercise}[1][]%
{%
  \begin{sqfexercises}
  \hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-0.1\textwidth}%
  \BODY%
  \end{minipage}
  \end{sqfexercises}
}
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% new theoremstyle for Exercises:  (unstarred exercise) theoremstyle
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{nostarexercises}
{5pt plus1pt minus1pt}
{5pt plus1pt minus1pt}
{\normalfont}
{0pt}
{\normalfont}
{}
{0pt}
{\nbast\thmnumber{#2.}~\thmname{#1}\thmnote{~{\normalfont(#3)}}}%% Custom Theorem Head SPEC
\makeatother
%%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\theoremstyle{nostarexercises}
\newtheorem{nexercises}[exer]{\protect\exername}
%%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\environfinalcode{\ignorespacesafterend}
\NewEnviron{nexercise}[1][]%
{%
  \begin{nexercises}
  \hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-0.1\textwidth}%
  \BODY%
  \end{minipage}
  \end{nexercises}
}
%%==============================================================================
\newcommand*{\fmap}[1]{\ensuremath{#1\colon}}
\newcommand*{\zvert}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{Vert}{(#1)}}}

\setcounter{chapter}{11} 
%%==============================================================================
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Complexes}
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection*{\normalfont\scshape{Exercises}}\label{exer:SimplicialComplexes}
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{sexercise}
Define a relation $R$ on $\zvert{K}$ by $vRw$ if there exists an edge path in $K$ from $v$ to $w$.
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=(\roman*),widest=iii,font=\normalfont,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
\item\label{12SimComExer37i} Show that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\zvert{K}$.
\item\label{12SimComExer37ii} For each $x\in \zvert{K}$, define the \textbf{component} of $K$ containing $x$ as the family of all simplexes $s\in K$ with $\zvert{s}$ contained in the $R$-equivalence class of $x$. Show that each component of $K$ is a connected subcomplex and that $K$ is their disjoint union.
\item\label{12SimComExer37iii} If $x\in \zvert{K}$ and $L$ is the component of $K$ containing $x$, then
    \[
    \pi(K,x) \cong \pi(L,x).
    \]
\end{enumerate}
\label{12SimComExer37}
\end{sexercise}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{nexercise}
Define a relation $R$ on $\zvert{K}$ by $vRw$ if there exists an edge path in $K$ from $v$ to $w$.
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=(\roman*),widest=iii,font=\normalfont,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
\item\label{12SimComExer38i} Show that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\zvert{K}$.
\item\label{12SimComExer38ii} For each $x\in \zvert{K}$, define the \textbf{component} of $K$ containing $x$ as the family of all simplexes $s\in K$ with $\zvert{s}$ contained in the $R$-equivalence class of $x$. Show that each component of $K$ is a connected  subcomplex and that $K$ is their disjoint union.
\item\label{12SimComExer38iii} If $x\in \zvert{K}$ and $L$ is the component of $K$ containing $x$, then
    \[
    \pi(K,x) \cong \pi(L,x).
    \]
\end{enumerate}
\label{12SimComExer38}
\end{nexercise}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear, essentially the only reason to use a minipage in a context like this is to prevent page breaks, so it's a bit hard to suggest alternative, you can just simply delete the \begin{minipage} and \end{minipage} lines and it runs without error. But perhaps the underlying question is that you want some differemt layout?

Comment: Hello David, My goal is to produce an output with exercise/question numbers against the left margin of the page and the text of of the exercise left aligned at a fixed distance from the left margin. But with  itemization mixed in with text the only way I could find is to is to box the text in a minipage a fraction of linewidth from the left margin.  Then my problem arose; on some pages the vertical space between pairs of exercises widened. I learned that the minipage format is preventing page breaks of exercise block close to the end of the page.  Please pardon this novice.

Comment: you certainly don't want any sort of box, it sounds like you just need a nested lists with the list indent specified accordingly but I'm not sure I understood the required layout enough to suggest code

Comment: David, thank you for your advice and suggestion. The nested list approach worked perfectly; the exercise blocks break neatly across page boundaries. My 2nd MWE attest to that fact. I now need to figure out how to give you some gold badges.

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution to the posted question; lots of thanks to David for his advice and suggestions.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{enumitem,environ,calc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,bm}
%\usepackage{layout}
%\usepackage{showframe}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Redefining Section Command
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection
                    {section}%                                 %% name
                    {1}%                                       %% level
                    {0pt}%                                     %% no indent from left margin
                    {-1\baselineskip minus\parskip}%           %% beforeskip
                    {0.4\baselineskip}%                        %% afterskip
                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\raggedright}}% %% style
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Redefining Subsection Command
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection
                        {subsection}%
                        {2}%
                        {0pt}%
                        {-\baselineskip}%
                        {0.2\baselineskip}%
                        {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\raggedright}}%
\makeatother
%%==============================================================================
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}[section]
\numberwithin{exer}{chapter}
%%==============================================================================
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% the following command definitions are used in the new exercise styles!
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newsavebox{\nbox}
\newcommand{\sbast}{\ensuremath{^{\ast}\mkern-1.5mu}}
\sbox\nbox{$\sbast$}
\newcommand{\nbast}{\ensuremath{\hspace{\the\wd\nbox}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Non-starred Exercise environment      nexercise
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\environfinalcode{\ignorespacesafterend}
\NewEnviron{nexercise}[1][]%
{%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \ignorespaces
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \begin{nExercises}
  \nexercize{\BODY}%
  \end{nExercises}
\par%
}
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newlist{nExercises}{enumerate}{2}%
%%----- list style parameters -----
\setlist[nExercises]{%
  label=\nbast\theexer.,                         % Label: Chapter.exercise number.
  align=left,                                    % Left align labels
  leftmargin=0.10\textwidth,                     % Space between margin of list and following lines
  labelwidth=*,                                  % Auto computation of width of label
  topsep=4pt plus0pt minus1pt,                   % Vertical space between preceding text and 1st item
  itemsep=0pt,                                   % Vertical space between pairs of items
  before=\normalfont                             % changing font before start of enumeration
%  before=\normalfont\small                       % changing font before start of enumeration
}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\nexercize}{%
  \refstepcounter{exer}                               % Add 1 to exercise counter
  \item\label{nlbl:\theexer.\arabic{nExercisesi}}%    % Append label to item
%--------------------------------------------------
  \setlist[enumerate, 1]{%
      leftmargin=*,
      label=(\roman*),
      itemsep=0pt,
      topsep=0pt
    }%            % Label for subexercises, but only within an exercise
}
%%==============================================================================
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Starred Exercise environment
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\environfinalcode{\ignorespacesafterend}
\NewEnviron{sexercise}[1][]%
{%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \ignorespaces
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \begin{sExercises}
  \sexercize{\BODY}%
  \end{sExercises}
\par%
}
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newlist{sExercises}{enumerate}{2}%
%%----- list style parameters -----
\setlist[sExercises]{%
  label=\sbast\theexer.,                         % Label: Exercise Chapter.exercise
  align=left,                                    % Left align labels
  leftmargin=0.10\textwidth,                     % Distance from Left edge of environ to left edge of list text
  labelwidth=*,                                  % Auto computation of width of label
  topsep=4pt plus0pt minus1pt,                   % Vertical space between preceding text and 1st item
  itemsep=0pt,                                   % Vertical space between pairs of items
  before=\normalfont                             % Changing font size before start of enumeration
}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\sexercize}{%
  \refstepcounter{exer}                               % Add 1 to exercise counter
  \item\label{slbl:\theexer.\arabic{sExercisesi}}%    % Append label to item
%--------------------------------------------------
  \setlist[enumerate, 1]{%
      leftmargin=*,
      label=(\roman*),
      itemsep=0pt,
      topsep=0pt
    }%            % Label for subexercises, but only within an exercise
}
%%==============================================================================
\newcommand*{\fmap}[1]{\ensuremath{#1\colon}}
\newcommand{\bast}{\ensuremath{\bm{\ast}}}
\newcommand*{\zvert}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{Vert}{(#1)}}}

\setcounter{chapter}{11}
%%==============================================================================
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Complexes}
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection*{\normalfont\scshape{Exercises}}\label{exer:SimplicialComplexes}
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{nexercise}
Define a relation $R$ on $\zvert{K}$ by $vRw$ if there exists an edge path in $K$ from $v$ to $w$.
\begin{enumerate}[align=left,leftmargin=*,label=(\roman*),widest=iii,font=\normalfont,topsep=0pt,nosep]
\item\label{12SimComExer37i} Show that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\zvert{K}$.
\item\label{12SimComExer37ii} For each $x\in \zvert{K}$, define the \textbf{component} of $K$ containing $x$ as the family of all simplexes $s\in K$ with $\zvert{s}$ contained in the $R$-equivalence class of $x$. Show that each component of $K$ is a connected subcomplex and that $K$ is their disjoint union.
\item\label{12SimComExer37iii} If $x\in \zvert{K}$ and $L$ is the component of $K$ containing $x$, then
    \[
    \pi(K,x) \cong \pi(L,x).
    \]
\end{enumerate}
\label{12SimComExer37}
\end{nexercise}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\addtocounter{exer}{21}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{sexercise}
Consider the set $[X,A]$, wher $A$ is a fixed space. Show that a continuous map $\fmap{f}X\to Y$ gives rise to a function $\fmap{f_{\bast}}[X,A]\to [Y,A]$ with the following properties.
\begin{enumerate}[align=left,leftmargin=*,label=(\roman*),widest=iii,font=\normalfont,topsep=0pt,nosep]
\item\label{12SimComExer39i} If $f\simeq g$, then $f_{\bast}=g_{\bast}$.
\item\label{12SimComExer39ii} If $\fmap{1}X\to X$ is the identity map, then $1_{\bast}$ is the identity function.
\item\label{12SimComExer39iii} If $\fmap{g}Y\to Z$ is another continuous map, then $(qf)_{\bast}=g_{\bast}f_{\bast}$.
\end{enumerate}
Deduce that if $X\simeq Y$ there is a $(1-1)$-correspondence between the sets $[X,A]$ and $[Y,A]$.\par
What are the corresponding results for the sets $[X,A]$, for a fixed space $A$?
\label{12SimComExer39}
\end{sexercise}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it) or with `ctrl + k`.

Comment: +1. Writing `$(1-1)$-correspondence` seems wrong, though, as `1` isn't being substracted from `1`, is it? You may want to write `1--1 correspondence` instead. And, to "tuck" the subscript asterisk a bit closer in to `f`, consider writing `f_{\mkern-2mu\bast}` instead of `f_{\bast}`.

Comment: Hi Mico, You are correct; the (1-1)-correspondence is the textual one-to-one correspondence.  I appreciate the correction and your suggestions. Please, you may improve on the answer. I'm quite new to the TeX/LaTeX knowledge world.